# Why isn't the turtle command for filling colour accepting my input?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code which is supposed to define a function that draws a square with a given start point, height, width and colour using turtle:

```
def jump(t, x, y):
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown()

def make_turtle(x, y):
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    jump(t, x, y)
    return t

def rectangle(x, y, width, height, color):
    t = make_turtle(x, y)
    t.hideturtle()
    t.fillcolor(color)
    t.begin_fill()
    for dist in [width, height, width, height]:
        t.forward(dist)
        t.left(90)
    t.end_fill()
```

When I run it I get the following error message:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'red' is not defined
```

Now it seems like nothing works, as I get the same response for every code with turtle I try.

Comment: where is the `red` in your code?

Comment: Running what? Those are only function definitions. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have probably specified the color as a variable rather than a string

```
.rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4, red)
```

instead of

```
.rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4, 'red')
```